# A shocker in soccer, pt. 3

Tags: riddle, rhyme, poetry

> I can be sticky but you must be picky;
>   Many of me define the key, of a galaxy;
>   I'm a type when I'm ripe;
>   And you must pay a tax when I'm in stacks.

What am I?

*Note: This riddle takes the form of [A shocker](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/94099/a-shocker-in-soccer?noredirect=1&lq=1) [in soccer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/94242/a-shocker-in-soccer-pt-2). The key is to figure out which second half of the line matches up with which first half before solving for the word or phrase.*

Comment: Interesting genre of riddle. Similar to my [Reassemble the riddles](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/43085/5373), if you'll pardon the self-promotion :-)

Comment: Oh, I like that! Interesting that we came up with similar ideas to complicate "what am I" riddles.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the answer is:

> Note

My arrangement of the riddle is:

> *Many of me define the key but you must be picky*
>
>  Talking about a musical key, e.g. for a guitar each key is made up of 7 **notes** "picked" from the 12 notes available
>
>  *I'm a type of a galaxy*
>
>  Referring to the Samsung Galaxy **Note** range of smart phones
>
>  *I can be sticky when I'm in stacks*
>
>  Good old stacks of sticky post-it **notes**
>
>  *And you must pay a tax when I'm ripe*
>
>  I'm a little less comfortable with this one. I *think* it refers to a debit **note** which becomes "ripe" when it is due and a payment is owed.

Disclaimer

> My musical theory is pretty shaky (non-existent), the reasoning behind the key might be a bit dodgy. It is based on some rather rushed research and [this article](http://uncletim.com/Newsletter/How-Keys-Work-On-A-Guitar.htm).

Comment: Your explanations for all 4 (Including "key" and "ripe") are exactly what I intended, nicely done! :) p.s. there are probably more accurate financial terms than "tax" but it rhymed with "stacks" so I used it.

Comment: Keys are used in more than just rot13(thvgnef). Still work, though.